# Code Emulator for FPU numbers

Tags: assembly, x86

Does anyone has an emulator that will calculate a sum of two FPU 4-byte numbers without fadd instruction? Or can anyone explain to me the algorithm?

Comment: This is really too broad a question for SO. Perhaps you could actually write some code and then present your issues.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> sum of two FPU 4-byte numbers without fadd instruction

```
fld op1      ; op1
fldz         ; op1, 0
fsub op2     ; op1, -op2
fsubp        ; op1+op2
fstp result
```

Comment: Ask a silly question, get a silly answer :)